# Timeout / no results with FQL on url_like to determine if user or his friends likes an external site

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to determine if a user or his friends already like a specified external URL. Using the Graph API Explorer, I am trying to perform this FQL: `SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE url="<URL>" AND (user_id = me() OR user_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))`

I do not get back any results, the AJAX bar keeps on spinning.

A simpler query leaving out the friends connection works fine, such as `fql?q=SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() AND url = "<URL>"`

Is there a problem with my query? Is there an alternative way to achieve my result?

Thanks,
Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be happening, if you run the query against just your own UID, then it'll work pretty much instantly, so I think this is a bug. You should file a report in the [Facebook Platform Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

Comment: @Stefan, be sure to report back here with a bug # so others who stumble across this question on stackoverflow can easily go to it.  Thanks!